# Change the order or remove custom properties with Verge3D

Tags: materials, node-editor, properties

[image]

When I use a material created to render cycle I can not convert them for Verge3d. How to do ? Remove API cycle ?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do this step by step:

1. Delete all cycles nodes in the material
2. Click on *Use Shader Nodes* on the material to disable it
3. Switch to *Verge3D* engine
4. Enable *Node Material* on the *Material* tab and use *Verge3D Nodes* only.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what are you think when your have multiple custom on each other ? Everything is kept in memory.